# Gracefully exit/close a Windows application using Python

Tags: python, windows

I want to make a graceful exit from an external windows application to automate a workflow. I DO NOT want to KILL the app as there is a process which runs only if the app is closed gracefully. Killing the app does not run that process.
Is there any way I can achieve that!!

Comment: Sent a SIGINT or SIGTERM?

Comment: If you can modify that Windows app, you can add some simple inter-process communication. The easiest is to register a C++ signal handler.

Comment: yes, as said before: send a signal to the app. If you have access to its code it's easy: register a callback for the signal of your choice/catch the appropriate message from the win-msg-queue. Otherwise, try to terminate the app sending other standard signals, e.g. the ones suggested above. Most applications listen to signals in order to terminate gracefully. Research the signals available

Comment: The Windows kernel doesn't have POSIX signals as an IPC mechanism, so sending `SIGTERM` is not an option. Is this a GUI application? In that case you send a `WM_CLOSE` message to the top-level windows, found via [`EnumWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497) and [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522).